# How to validate xml (input stream or string reader) against xsd in jibx

Tags: xml, xsd, jibx

I am new to jibx and would like to know whether validation of xml against xsd is available.
If yes please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

There's no quick/easy way; the author of JibX suggests using StAX. Here is a link to the formal feature request which also includes more detail on using StAX meanwhile.

http://jira.codehaus.org/i#browse/JIBX-381